# angular 2 add new column, with textbox, dynamically in table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col.descr}}</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]=row[col.name] (ngModelChange)="changeCheck($event)"/>
            {{row[col.name]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="addColumn()"> Add column </button>
</div>
```

and I need to add a column enter data and save.

How can insert a new column using html and typescript?

Comment: Please provide more information, such as how does your `columns` and `rows` construct look like.

Comment: You will have tu update the columns array from component only

Comment: What you actually want when you click addcolumn and what should happen.